# How do I get data from Javascript function and save it to a user's custom meta field in php?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, post, onesignal

I'm working with a service that automatically registers my user's devices with Onesignal.

I call the function on login by calling `gonative_onesignal_info();` inside script tags (full function will be below). That registers devices perfectly fine with Onesignal.

Now, according to the service's documentation, I can POST it to my server via AJAX, which is what I'm struggling with. From the documentation for the service, if you call gonative_onesignal_info() like this:

```
function gonative_onesignal_info(info) {
    console.log(info);
}
```

... info will look like this:

```
{
    oneSignalUserId: 'xxxxxxx',
    oneSignalPushToken: 'xxxxxx',
    oneSignalSubscribed: true,
}
```

And here's my full function:

```
function onesignal_mobile_registration( $user_login, $user ) {

    // Get user data
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;

    ?>

        <script>
            gonative_onesignal_info(info);
        </script>

    <?php

    $oneSignalPushToken = ???;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'oneSignalPushToken', $oneSignalPushToken);

}
add_filter( 'wp_login', 'onesignal_mobile_registration', 10, 2 );
```

So, how can I extract the *oneSignalPushToken* from that Javascript option, and store it in $oneSignalPushToken to be saved to my user? I think I need to use AJAX to pull it out, right? How would I do that?

Comment: In which platform you are working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a php variable from javascript because php run in server but javascript run in browser. You must get `$oneSignalPushToken` value from a php source OR call a ajax from browser when send js data to php variable:

Script place:

```
<script>
    var data = gonative_onesignal_info(info);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'test.php?oneSignalPushToken=' + data.oneSignalPushToken, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

test.php

```
function onesignal_mobile_registration( $user_login, $user ) {

    // Get user data
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;

    $oneSignalPushToken = $_GET['oneSignalPushToken'];
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'oneSignalPushToken', $oneSignalPushToken);

}
add_filter( 'wp_login', 'onesignal_mobile_registration', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand what your code does:

- The PHP part will render an HTML page
- The JavaScript part will execute in the browser once the page is fully rendered and served

That means you won't be able to retrieve a JavaScript variable in the PHP thread that generates the page, for two main reasons:

- JavaScript and PHP execution contexts are not shared at all
- JavaScript will execute once the PHP thread has ended

What you have to do is expose an endpoint on your PHP server, let's say `POST` on a `/token` URL. You will call this endpoint from your JavaScript with some code like `fetch('/token', { method: 'POST', body: info });`, then retrieve the token from the `$_POST` global variable, and then execute your `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'oneSignalPushToken', $oneSignalPushToken);` line